# Error overloading function with different template template parameters with same argument

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading, template-templates

I have a class that gets two template template parameters and overloads a function with an argument that is either the one or the other template template parameter but both times with the same template argument:

```
template<template<typename> class TemplArgA, template<typename> class TemplArgB>
class CompileError {
public:
  void func(TemplArgA<int> x) {}
  void func(TemplArgB<int> x) {}
};
```

I am using VC2010 and get

```
error C2535: 'void CompileError<TemplArgA,TemplArgB>::func(TemplArgA<int>)': member function already defined or declared
```

when compiling the above code sample (not even at template instantiation, just to have the above lines in the code already causes the compile error).

These in contrast compile fine:

```
template<class TemplArgA, class TemplArgB>
class Compiles {
public:
  void func(TemplArgA x) {}
  void func(TemplArgB x) {}
};

template<template<typename> class TemplArgA, template<typename> class TemplArgB>
class AlsoCompiles {
public:
  void func(TemplArgA<int>    x) {}
  void func(TemplArgB<double> x) {}
};
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Seems to compile fine with clang++, so I wonder whether it might be a bug in VC2010 ... If so: Any idea how to work around it?

Comment: Why not use 2017?

Comment: Don't have a choice, **must** use VC2010 :(

Comment: VC chokes on the template definition itself, or is it the instantiation that causes problems?

Comment: Template definition itself.

Answer (score 2):

> Don't have a choice, must use VC2010 :(
>
> If so: Any idea how to work around it?

so, you may try

```
template<template<typename> class TemplArgA, template<typename> class TemplArgB>
class CompileError {
public:
void func(TemplArgA<int> x) {}
void func(TemplArgB<int> x,void* workaround = 0) {}
```

of course, this is not strictly equivalent to your original code though (because you'll not get an error until function instantation in the TemplArgA==TemplArgB case; I don't know if this is relevant for you or not)

> But in the real code, I don't have just TemplArgA and TemplArgB, but 4 template template parameters (say TemplArgA to TemplArgD) -- I don't think I can apply the workaround then?

you just need to persuade the compiler that those overloads are not equivalent:

```
template<int> struct workaround_t{};

void func(TemplArgA<int> x, workaround_t<0>* workaround = 0) {}
void func(TemplArgB<int> x, workaround_t<1>* workaround = 0) {}
void func(TemplArgC<int> x, workaround_t<2>* workaround = 0) {}
//...
```

Comment: I think the TemplArgA==TemplArgB case would not give an error until function instantiation in either case, isn't it? Anyway, it's not relevant for me.

Comment: @thilo, no, in your original code (I mean, for a conforming compiler) you'll get an error as soon as the class template gets instantiated ( but, I'm not sure to what extent such diagnostic is required standard-wise, I should check that ... )

Comment: Compiles with the suggested workaround, nice idea.

But in the real code, I don't have just TemplArgA and TemplArgB, but 4 template template parameters (say TemplArgA to TemplArgD) -- I don't think I can apply the workaround then? :(

Comment: @thilo, as a side note, according to [temp.inst/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.spec#temp.inst-2), I confirm that the ArgA==ArgB case is required to be diagnosed at class template instantiation for the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is that the compiler see and error the possible istantiation win `TemplArgA == TemplaArgB` (when the two `func()` collide) so I suppose that (if you can use C++11) another workaround is SFINAE enable (or not) the second `func()` only id `TemplArgA != TemplArgB`

I mean something like

```
template <template <typename> class C1, template <typename> class C2>
struct bar
 {
   void func (C1<int> x)
    { }

   template <template <typename> class D2 = C2>
   typename std::enable_if<    std::is_same<C2<int>, D2<int>>{}
                       &&  ( ! std::is_same<C1<int>, D2<int>>{})>::type
      func (D2<int> x)
    { }    

 };
```

The OP add:

> in the real code, I don't have just `TemplArgA` and `TemplArgB`, but 4 template template parameters (say `TemplArgA` to `TemplArgD`)

My solution become really ugly (the third function

```
   template <template <typename> class D3 = C3>
   typename std::enable_if<    std::is_same<C3<int>, D3<int>>{}
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C1<int>, D3<int>>{})       
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C2<int>, D3<int>>{})>::type
      func (D3<int> x)
    { }
```

and the fourth

```
   template <template <typename> class D4 = C4>
   typename std::enable_if<    std::is_same<C4<int>, D4<int>>{}
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C1<int>, D4<int>>{})       
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C2<int>, D4<int>>{})       
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C3<int>, D4<int>>{})>::type
      func (D4<int> x)
    { }
```

) but I hope could work.

The following is a full working (but with g++ and clang++; I don't with VC2010) example

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename> struct foo1 { };
template <typename> struct foo2 { };
template <typename> struct foo3 { };
template <typename> struct foo4 { };


template <template <typename> class C1, template <typename> class C2,
          template <typename> class C3, template <typename> class C4>
struct bar
 {
   void func (C1<int> x)
    { }

   template <template <typename> class D2 = C2>
   typename std::enable_if<    std::is_same<C2<int>, D2<int>>{}
                       &&  ( ! std::is_same<C1<int>, D2<int>>{})>::type
      func (D2<int> x)
    { }

   template <template <typename> class D3 = C3>
   typename std::enable_if<    std::is_same<C3<int>, D3<int>>{}
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C1<int>, D3<int>>{})       
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C2<int>, D3<int>>{})>::type
      func (D3<int> x)
    { }

   template <template <typename> class D4 = C4>
   typename std::enable_if<    std::is_same<C4<int>, D4<int>>{}
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C1<int>, D4<int>>{})       
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C2<int>, D4<int>>{})       
                        && ( ! std::is_same<C3<int>, D4<int>>{})>::type
      func (D4<int> x)
    { }
 };


int main ()
 {
   bar<foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4>  b1234;
   bar<foo1, foo1, foo1, foo1>  b1111;
   bar<foo1, foo1, foo1, foo2>  b1112;
   bar<foo1, foo1, foo2, foo1>  b1121;
   bar<foo1, foo2, foo1, foo1>  b1211;
   bar<foo2, foo1, foo1, foo1>  b2111;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround that works for me:

```
enum eSelector { S_A, S_B };

template<template<typename,eSelector> class TemplArg>
class Workaround {
public:
  void func(TemplArg<int, S_A> x) {}
  void func(TemplArg<int, S_B> x) {}
};
```

This way, VC2010 compiles without C2535. It makes the classes to be provided as template arguments more complicated. I formally had classed

```
template<typename T> class MyA { ... };
template<typename T> class MyB { ... };
```

that I used as template arguments, now use partial template specialization like

```
template<typename T, eSelector S> class MyAB;
template<typename T> class MyAB<T, S_A> { ... };
template<typename T> class MyAB<T, S_B> { ... };

template<typename T> class MyA : public MyAB<T, S_A> { /* `forward' constructor implementations */ };
template<typename T> class MyB : public MyAB<T, S_B> { /* `forward' constructor implementations */ };
```

Anyway, things look much more complicated than they need to be with this approach, so I'm not really satisfied with this. I will try with Massimiliano's suggestion from his edited post, think that will make the code look less frightening; still I wanted to provide this approach for the sake of completeness ;)

I still wonder whether I you missed out something important or whether it is a VC2010 bug ...

Comment: "I still wonder..." It surely is a vc bug, see [temp.type/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.type#1)