# VS2017 - Error overloading function with different template template parameters with same argument

Tags: function, c++11, templates, visual-c++, overloading

Error overloading function with different template template parameters with same argument

In VS2017 I am getting an error

> error C2535: 'bool

However, the two function declarations clearly have different arguments.

This code compiles fine on GCC.

I found a similar error here:

[Error overloading function with different template template parameters with same argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057344/error-overloading-function-with-different-template-template-parameters-with-same/47057752)

Could anybody suggest a solution as I want to code to be the same for linux and windows and compile with both GCC and MSVC.

Comment: I think it would be best if you prepared minimal example, that can be copy pasted into favourite programming environment, so people could start hacking to work around the issue. Your snippet misses class definitions. BTW. does the solution with bogus default argument from the other question not work in your case?

Comment: @luk32 thank you, I've provide the full class as example. I couldn't quite follow the other solution, how would you suggest to implement it.

Comment: I don't see any template template parameter here. Function parameter types are *types*, not templates or anything. `first_graph::node` is a type. `second_graph::node` is a type. If they are the same type, you will get the error. The snippet is by no means enough to determine that, because it doesn't define `graph`.

Comment: [This](https://ideone.com/JXFmlB) is my idea of what your code actually boils down. As you can see it doesn't compile on GCC. If this is not what you have in mind, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m Also `node` is nested class within `graph`. It is not `typdef` like in `struct a` in your example.

Comment: @n.m I think this is more accurate example. [link](https://ideone.com/KcWFGn)

Comment: If your example doesn't compile with MSVC and gives the same error message, you should include it in the question instead of your original code. Since it [does compile](https://godbolt.org/z/QsICSs) it doesn't represent the problem Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `first_graph` and `second_graph` may be different types, but `first_graph::node` and `second_graph::node` look like the same type.

Comment: @n.m I'm sorry for the confusion. Here is the read code. It compiles on GCC and ideone.com but if you copy/paste it to visual studio it won't compile. [code](https://ideone.com/WnmIns)

Comment: The fact that it compiles with gcc doesn't mean anything because you never instantiate the template. Show a program with at least one object of type `conjoined_graph<whatever>` created. Note that you need to pass an allocator to it. Since you never define anything that could serve as an allocator, I cannot try it myself. Please also read once again what [mcve] means. The first word is spelled "minimal".

Comment: @n.m Apologies if I have frustrated you, I appreciate the help. TBH its my first time really working with templates and allocaters so I'm a bit lost. Moving from linux to windows has made it harder. But anyway it would be nice to find the cause. if there is a netter IDE online for sharing code I could use that if you prefer so I could separate the header files. For now I will update the example and repost shortly.

Comment: I charge $400/hour for consulting services. Post your question on stackoverflow in a format appropriate for stackoverflow, and I will answer it for free. Please understand that it is your responsibility to provide a [mcve]. If you wrote all this code, you should understand how to reduce it to manageable size.

Comment: @n.m OK thanks I understand, it will be at least a week for me to reduce it. I didn't write any of it I'm just trying to compile it with VS. Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: I have reduced your code to 20 lines. [Here it is](https://godbolt.org/z/gW9h1o). It appears to be a bug in MSVC. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/WjS3mu)'s a workaround.

Comment: @n.m thank you very much for your help today. I really appreciate the effort you went to reducing the code. I am now going to go away and study this and learn from it. Have a good evening.

Comment: @n.m may I ask did you you find this issue and workaround online? do have any links you could share? I'm just curious as to how to thought to introduce `struct ID`? Thanks

Comment: I just experimented and found a solution, I don't think there's anything online about this.

Comment: @n.m ah OK thank you. How would you best describe this bug in your own words? as I may submit it to MS. Would it be something like "unable to overload functions in a template as types of arguments cannot be distinguished as unique"?

Comment: I'd say VS incorrectly resolves dependent type names in presence of certain multiple inheritance patterns. Don't see any reason why it would do so.